# How to update all dependencies to a specific version

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Angular 6 to 7. There are a massive amount of dependencies that also need to be upgraded, but all I can find are tutorials to upgrade everything to the latest version (which would be v8)--not to a specific version. What is the proper procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

This command will update your project to latest version of angular. but if you want to upgrade to specific version then you have to add `@version` in dependency as below

```
ng update @angular/cli@7.0.0 @angular/core@7.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Angular has Upgrade](https://update.angular.io/) page. Which will tell you how to upgrade angular related stuff